# Spotlight indexing occasionally throws Error Returned from daemon: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=9 in console

Tags: spotlight, catalina, console

For the past week Spotlight on my Mac has been indexing my 256GB drive, using about 200% CPU more or less constantly and it hasn't gone anywhere, so today I opened up the console and filtered by Spotlight processes. It's mostly just "successfully fetched policies" but every so often (every few minutes) there's an error message that says "Error Returned from daemon: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=9" Is this what is causing the problems? What does it mean? How do I fix it?

System Specs: [image]

Comment: do you have xcode or such type of tool installed during your last week period ?

Comment: @Udhy I've got Xcode Command Line tools for Homebrew but I can install the full app if needed.